# How to keep BOM from removal from Perforce unicode files

Tags: unicode, utf-8, perforce

I have converted entire branch with .NET and SQL sources to **UTF-8 with BOM**, having their Perforce file type changed to *Unicode* in the same operation. (Encoding difference might sound confusing, but in Perforce, *Unicode* file type denotes UTF-8 file content.) But later I have found out that Perforce silently elliminates BOM marker from UTF-8 files. Is it possible to set Perforce to keep UTF-8 BOM markers in files of *Unicode* file type? I can't find it documented.

Perforce server is switched to *Unicode* mode, connection encoding is *UTF-8* no BOM (but changing it to *UTF-8 with BOM* doesn't make any difference).

Example:

1. check out a source file from Perforce
2. change file type to *Unicode*
3. convert file content to format "UTF-8 with BOM"
4. submit the file (now the file still keeps BOM in first 3 bytes)
5. remove the file from workspace
6. get the latest revision of the file (now the file doesn't contain BOM at the beginning)

Comment: Pay attention to the P4CHARSET value.  If it is "utf8" then it will strip the BOM, use "utf8-bom" instead.  [More here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/i18nnotes.txt).

Comment: @HansPassant - Thank you Hans, it helped. Please add this as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I was just guessing at it.  Please post your own answer and explain what the you found and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, Hans Passant's comment encouraged me to re-examine P4CHARSET and finally, the answer has two parts:

---

**For Perforce command line access**, setting of `P4CHARSET` variable controls the behavior. To enable adding BOM to files of *Unicode* type, use command

```
p4 set P4CHARSET=utf8-bom
```

In order to have these files *without* BOM, use

```
p4 set P4CHARSET=utf8
```

---

**For P4V The Perforce Visual Client**, the setting can be changed via menu `Connection` > `Choose Character Encoding...`. Use value `Unicode (UTF-8)` to enable adding BOM and `Unicode (UTF-8, no BOM)` to suppress it.

- if menu item `Choose Character Encoding...` is disabled, ensure the following (and then check again)

  - P4V has connection to server open and working
  - pane containing depot/workspace tree is focused (click inside to re-ensure this)

---

**Notes:**

- **if you usually combine both above ways to access Perforce**, you need to apply both solutions, otherwise you will keep getting mixed results
- **if you want to instantly add/remove BOM to/from existing files**, adjust the above settings, then remove files from workspace and add them again (see steps **5** and **6** of example posted in the question). Other server actions changing content of files (integrating, merging etc.) will do the similar
- **for other encoding options and their impact on BOM**, see the second table in [Internationalization Notes for P4D, the Perforce Server and Perforce client applications](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/user/i18nnotes.txt)

Comment: I followed your steps, but still get BOM files.

Comment: @Leon – you can verify whether your new settings are correct. If you are still having issues, open new question and describe in detail what did you set, what did you try and what is still not working.

Comment: can you help to look at this case?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320814/how-to-remove-bom-from-files-in-p4-server-when-downloading

Comment: P4V menu item "Choose Character Encoding" is disabled on my computer (even after focusing depot tree).

Comment: Does not work for me. I have winansi server (unicode enabled) and winansi P4V client (2017.2). UTF8-BOM files can't be diffed at crucible/fisheye. So I need to map file type back to text, which is kinda ugly hack.

Comment: @Silvos – at the time of the answer this worked. If you find more up-to-date answer, feel free to add it. Or you can add a new follow-up question explicitly addressing new server and client (to avoid marking as duplicate).

Comment: Too bad that there seems to be no option to respect the input files (keep BOM if they have it, don't add BOM if they don't have it)