# VS2010 doesn't understand the string encoding of its own files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, character-encoding, mfc, perforce

I am working with VS2010 project Unicode which all works fine. When I remove my local files and download fresh copy of it from source control (Perforce), the `resource.h` file reads wrong (in chinese).

//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}} ਍⼀⼀ 䴀椀挀爀漀猀漀昀琀 嘀椀猀甀愀氀 䌀⬀⬀ 最攀渀攀爀愀琀攀搀 椀渀挀氀甀搀攀 昀椀氀攀⸀ഀഀ // Used by MyDemo.rc ਍⼀⼀ഀഀ #define IDM_ABOUTBOX                    0x0010 ਍⌀搀攀昀椀渀攀 䤀䐀䐀开䄀䈀伀唀吀䈀伀堀                    ㄀　　ഀഀ

Why does VS2010 does that? and how can I fix it? It is essentially an identical file but in once instance it opens and a new instance it is not able to figure out the file encoding.

Although this is MFC project but it doesn't look like that has anything to do with this issue.

Comment: why do you put Chinese chars in the .h file? they should be in the rc file.

Comment: @Matt That's the problem, there are NO chinese characters in this file, its a typical English resource.h file (I haven't added anything to it manually).

Comment: Check the encoding the .h file.

Comment: I played with encoding and all encoding shows garbage. I end up coping the file over from the directory where it was working and the same file works here too. When I do file difference with source control version, it says they are identical but apparently they are not. Should probably use hex compare.

Comment: Perforce has a knack for mangling source file encoding.  Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204743/how-to-keep-bom-from-removal-from-perforce-unicode-files).

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a problem with Perforce's [line ending conversion](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3096) and a failure to correctly deduce the UTF16 format of resource.h

Following the steps [here](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/3488) may fix the problem if you encounter it in future:

> **Problem**
>
> On Windows, after syncing "text" (Perforce file type) files containing
>   utf16 encoding, the file in my workspace seems corrupted.
>
> **Solution**
>
> As the utf16 character encoding is a double byte character encoding
>   and Perforce treats "text" files as single byte, you may encounter
>   rendering or corruption issues in a Windows environment. Windows line
>   endings are not correctly converted within the UTF16 character set for
>   "text" files.  This corrupts the utf16 file content.
>
> File revisions with utf16 content should always be submitted using the
>   "utf16" file type (on add, Perforce will automatically detect utf16
>   files unless the user or a typemap rule overrides this behavior).
>
> In order to fix your issue follow these steps:
>
> - Edit your workspace specification and change the value of the LineEnding field to "unix"
> - Force sync the file (no line ending conversion will be done)
> - Check that the workspace file is now rendered properly
> - Checkout the file(s), changing the file type to utf16 (change from "text" to "utf16")
> - Edit your workspace specification and change the value of the LineEnding field back to "local"
> - Submit a new revision of the file
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> p4 client bruno_ws
>   LineEnd: unix
> p4 sync -f myfile.txt
> p4 edit -t utf16 myfile.txt
> p4 client bruno_ws
>   LineEnd: local
> p4 submit -d "Fixing unicode file"
> ```

Comment: This sorted the encoding issue out for me. This is easily handled from the visual client following the steps provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have seen this issue before so I am going to answer this now that I figured it out. Somehow the `resource.h` encoding or format was messed up and I don't know why.I  haven't made any manual changes to it. Perforce was not able to detect changes and display both of them correctly side by side in comparison. However it didn't prompt "The files are identical" message that it normally does if files are identical. However If I do 'Revert unchanged files", it rolls it back not detecting changes.

I used hex comparison tool and the internals of the two files were different. I simply picked the one which was working. Also the file size was also different for some reason.

The correct file shows as following

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by MyDemo.rc
//
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX                    100
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Resource.h needs to be in ANSI format.
Sometimes Visual Studio converts it to Unicode and puts a 2 byte BOM in the beginning. However, when it is loaded in the IDE editor, it cannot recognize it and displays it as Chinese.
If you take a look with a hex editor, you will be able to read the file contents.

The solution is to use an independent text editor (I use Notepad++ or Notepad2) and make sure the file is encoded in ANSI format without BOM.
Then check in the file and don't open it with Visual Studio anymore.
If you need to do changes, always go through the external editor and make sure that after saving the encoding is still ANSI.

I don't know why this happens. My assumption is that the OS default locale is different from the VS Project Resource locale. Then the IDE gets confused and probably tries to convert the resource file to Unicode in order to avoid conversion problems, but Resource.h is not an ordinary text file. The compilers seem not to understand Unicode sources with BOM.