# BOM issue in unicode perforce server

Tags: perforce

**Steps to repro the issue:**

1. Add a file to my P4 server, the file is detected as 'utf8' file type.

   The file I added is utf8 encoding without BOM. 
   [image: The file I added is utf8 encoding without BOM.]

   nobomb show in vim

   [image: nobomb show in vim]

p4 client detect it as 'utf8'
[image: p4 client detect it as 'utf8']

**If I do the same steps on other device, the file type is detected as 'unicode';**

2. Delete the file from local, and then sync it from server. issue occur: the file become utf8 with BOM.

sync the file, the file become utf with BOM
[image: sync the file, the file become utf with BOM]

As you know, BOM in html file can cause lots of issue....Is there anyone who can help me to solve this issue?

**Environment:**

1. Client version: **Rev. Perforce Visual Client/MACOSX107X86_64/2015.2/1312139**
2. p4 server is in "unicode" mode.
3. P4CHARSET of the workstation is set to utf8. 
   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files of type 'utf8' always sync with the BOM - 'utf8' type is designed that way (see [relnotes](http://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/doc/user/relnotes.txt), #998379).  If you don't want the BOM you're going to have to change it to 'text' or 'unicode'.

What you describe is a known bug(job083614) in your 15.2: "if P4CHARSET=utf8 and server is unicode and file has bytes >x80 and is valid utf8" then file is detected as utf8, should be unicode.  This fix should hopefully (no promises) be in 16.2.

Earlier p4 clients <= 15.1 should detect it as 'unicode'.

If you don't want type 'utf8' but rather 'unicode':

- add your file with "p4 add -t unicode <file>"
- change the file's type before submitting.
- use typemap to make all files with certain extension add as
  'unicode'.
- use a client (p4v, p4 command line) <= 2015.1 to **add** the files.  Subsequent syncs/submits can be later versions.

You can also have a trigger to prevent utf8 file types from being submitted(change-submit)

Comment: @J B,  TNX, you save my day. rolling back p4 client version to 15.1 solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answers you are looking for can be found in [the Perforce Internationalization Notes](ftp://ftp.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/doc/user/i18nnotes.txt)

In your question, you linked to the 2014.2 Internationalization Notes, but the utf8 filetype is newer than that; it was added in the 2015.2 release. So evidently your server is at release 2015.2 or higher. I linked to the 2016.1 Internalization notes. It is best to read the notes for the exact version of the server you are using.

The way that the files appear on your workstation is a combination of:

1. The server's "unicode" setting: you appear to have a Unicode-enabled server
2. The file's type (unicode, utf8, or utf16): you appear to have files of type unicode and utf8, at least
3. The P4CHARSET of your workstation. As of release 2014.2, if you do not explicitly set P4CHARSET, the server will attempt to assign a value automatically.

Since it appears that you are using P4V to sync the files to your workstation, you also have to consider what settings P4V is applying on your behalf. You might find it more clear to start by using the 'p4' command-line tool to sync certain files to your workstation. You can then experiment with different file types, different P4CHARSET settings, etc., until you find the combination that gives you the results you expect.

But, again, be careful to note the **exact** versions of the client and server software that you are using, and to read the notes that apply **exactly** to those versions, as several of these behaviors have changed recently and that may be confusing you.

Comment: Hi Bryan. Tnx for your information. But I still can not find my answer.

Comment: 1. Yeah, my server is "unicode". 
2. The file I add is utf8 encoding.
3. P4CHARSET of the workstation is set to utf8.

As I mentioned, the file type is detected as utf8, when I add the file to P4 server. and after that, if I delete local file, and sync the file from server. the file become UTF with BOM.

Comment: where can you know utf8 filetype is added in 2015.2? The next description in the Document? 
//////////////////
#1210497 (Bug #79997) *
     p4 command line will try to discover a good character set
     to use if P4CHARSET is set to a wide character set like
     utf16.  p4 set will now allow -C and -Q before the 'set' verb.
     Case insensitive platforms now check for setting 'p4charset'
     to problematic values.

Comment: so if I use a client before 2015.2, it will never detect file as utf8?

Comment: I describe the issue again, would please read the issue description again?